# Recycle view is showing empty field

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

[image]

I this image I getting error recycler view is showing the empty rows did not understand why

**Below is my adapter code Please help me I am new to andorid**

```js
package com.business.kraftpaper.adapter;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;

import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import com.business.kraftpaper.R;
import com.business.kraftpaper.pojo.PartyStatementPOJO;
import com.business.kraftpaper.pojo.leftDashboardPOJO;

import java.util.List;

public class Party_Statement_Adapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<Party_Statement_Adapter.ViewHolder> {

    private List<PartyStatementPOJO> list_data;
    private Context context;

    public Party_Statement_Adapter(List<PartyStatementPOJO> list_data, Context context) {
        this.list_data = list_data;
        this.context = context;

    }

    @Override
    public Party_Statement_Adapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view= LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.allreportsadapterlayout_new,parent,false);
        return new Party_Statement_Adapter.ViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(Party_Statement_Adapter.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        final PartyStatementPOJO  reportsPOJO = list_data.get(position);

        if (reportsPOJO.getBalance().equals("null")){

            holder.parentViewDetails.setVisibility(View.GONE);

        }else{

            holder.order_number.setText(reportsPOJO.getBalance());
            holder.order_date.setText(reportsPOJO.getDate());
            holder.order_for.setText(reportsPOJO.getParticular());
            holder.mill_name.setText(reportsPOJO.getDebit_credit());

        }


    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return list_data.size();
    }

    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
        private TextView order_date, order_for, mill_name, order_number, billto, shipto;
        private ImageView lenaAmountImageView, denaAmountImageView;
        private Button layoutStartAction;
        private LinearLayout parentViewDetails, layout_receipt_name;

        public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            order_date = itemView.findViewById(R.id.date_text);
            order_for =  itemView.findViewById(R.id.credit_text);
            mill_name = itemView.findViewById(R.id.debit_text);
            order_number = itemView.findViewById(R.id.balance_text);

            parentViewDetails = itemView.findViewById(R.id.parentViewDetails);
            parentViewDetails.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

            layout_receipt_name = itemView.findViewById(R.id.layout_receipt_name);
            layout_receipt_name.setVisibility(View.GONE);

        }
    }
}
```

This is adapter code did not understand why this error is coming
I did not understand why this error is coming I have tried to clear the list but didnot work
also not getting null data from the server checked in logcat

Please Help me

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inside onBindViewHolder you have used "null" as a string it should be null

```
  if (reportsPOJO.getBalance().equals("null")) -- incorrect
```

better to use

```
  if (TextUtils.isEmpty(reportsPOJO.getBalance())
```

and set the visibility to gone.